# how i can do duty cycle sensor listener

Tags: android

i'm beginner android programming 
my question is how i can do duty cycle in sensors using the android such that i need to register the Acc sensor when the certain ON-period ( i.e 3 sec ) starts and log the data during this 3 sec only (what ever the type of data) regarding the state of sensor changing and un_registering the same sensor in the end of the ON-period (3 sec) exactly, then sensor enter in sleep cycle for Off-period(for example 10 sec) then repeat the operation again.

please help me if that possible in android or not, if if its possible tell me explicitly how i can do that ?

i tried to write this code but it is not verified what i need!!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    sensorManager= (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    sdCard =getExternalFilesDir(FileName);
    file = new File(sdCard,FileName);
    csd = new collected_sensor_data();
    update_timer = new Timer();
    t = new MyTask();
    update_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(t,0,3000);

}

class MyTask extends TimerTask {        
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
        //We must use this function in order to change the text view text
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                csd.onSensorChanged(event);

            }

        });  


        }
    }
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startSimulation();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopSimulation();
}

class collected_sensor_data implements SensorEventListener{

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        x= event.values[0];
        y= event.values[1];
        z= event.values[2];
        sum = x+y+z;
        tv1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

    }
}
public void startSimulation(){

    sensorManager.registerListener(csd ,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(csd,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}

public void stopSimulation(){
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(csd);
}
```

Comment: Your timer task isn't needed-  the framework will call your app when it has a sensor update.  You do not need to do any type of timer for it, and you definitely don't want to directly call onSensorChanged

Comment: but how can control on logging sensor data during ON period only?

Comment: i need to allows sensor to gather data with normal rate along of ON-period (3 sec e.g) and stop reading (un-register) for off period (5 sec e.g) and soon.
this is concept of duty cycle . how i can do that?!!

Comment: Ok, then you do need a timer, but you don't want to call onSensorChanged in it.  You want to instead unregister the sensor listener (or reregister it after the 5s timer).  Or you can just never unregister it and keep a flag that swaps from true to false when the timer goes off, and you ignore all sensor updates when the flag is off.